# How to use mobile Internet on trains effectively?

Tags: browser, mobile-data, proxy, download-manager

When I'm on a train ride (mostly in Germany) I often find that this results in very poor mobile Internet connectivity on my Android devices.

Particularly, loading of even small web pages may take eons. I suspect that this is due to switching between mobile network cells while the train is in motion.

Even more annoyingly, this phenomenon can result in pages never finishing to load. Even though the device claims to still have mobile connection (albeit poor signal strength), the web browser gives up on loading pages over and over again.

In my opinion, this problem could be mitigated by setting a huge timeout value and/or caching partly retrieved pages on the device:

1. If I could set a really large timeout value for the web browser (Android browser, Chrome for Android or any other browser), the page would probably still take a long time to load, but at least, it would work out eventually, instead of aborting page load continuously.
2. If the browser (or some proxy server app on the device) would cache the parts of a web page it successfully retrieved and continue from there (using HTTP `Range` requests), it would be able to present the entire page eventually. (Similar to how a *download manager* works, except that it's for every web page.)

Is there any Android browser (or some kind of proxy app) that allows for setting appropriately large timeout values?

Alternatively, is there any Android app that allows for surfing the web in a "download manager" kind of way, picking up where it left off when the connection went bad?

Comment: some browsers have 'read it later' functionality, which allow you to load the pages in advance, if you know what to load when you do have good connectivity. Though this wouldn't solve the problem, something you can use to reduce the pain.

Comment: Have you tried switching to 2G or 3G? Because of larger coverage network switching should be easier.

Comment: @Madushan The "read it later" functionality is really helpful if you already found a web page and you would like to take a closer look at it later on. However, just to clarify, the scope of this question is that you're actually browsing the web looking for new pages to read.

Comment: @Janekmuric I should try that next time and see if it helps!